# Can't resolve 'tslint-loader' in webpack

Tags: webpack, tslint

How could I resolve this error?

```
C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\typescript>webpack
Hash: e7e95477931a6dc7fba6
Version: webpack 3.3.0
Time: 61ms

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslint-loader' in 'C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\typescript'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it using `npm link tslink tslint-loader`

Comment: seems you give typo answer, it must be:

npm link tslint tslint-loader